# Does a WHERE clause that matches a column value to itself get optimized out in SQL Server 2008+?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to clean up some stored procedures, and was curious about the following. I did a search, but couldn't find anything that really talked about performance.

## Explanation

Imagine a stored procedure that has the following parameters defined:

```
@EntryId uniqueidentifier,
@UserId int = NULL
```

I have the following table:

**tbl_Entry**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EntryId PK, uniqueidentifier | Name nvarchar(140) | Created datetime | UserId int |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

All columns are `NOT NULL`.

The idea behind this stored procedure is that you can get an Entry by its `uniqueidentifier` PK and, optionally, you can validate that it has the given `UserId` assigned by passing that as the second parameter. Imagine administrators who can view all entries versus a user who can only view their own entries.

### Option 1 (current)

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(3000);

SET @sql = N'
    SELECT
        a.EntryId,
        a.Name,
        a.UserId,
        b.UserName
    FROM
        tbl_Entry a,
        tbl_User b
    WHERE
        a.EntryId = @EntryId
        AND b.UserId = a.UserId';

IF @UserId IS NOT NULL
    SET @sql = @sql + N' AND a.UserId = @UserId';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

### Option 2 (what I thought would be better)

```
SELECT
    a.EntryId,
    a.Name,
    a.UserId,
    b.UserName

FROM
    tbl_Entry a,
    tbl_User b

WHERE
    a.EntryId = @EntryId
    AND a.UserId = COALESCE(@UserId, a.UserId)
    AND b.UserId = a.UserId;
```

I realize this case is fairly, simple, and could likely be optimized by a single IF statement that separates two queries. I wrote a simple case to try and concisely explain the issue. ***The actual stored procedure has 6 nullable parameters***. There are others that have even more nullable parameters. Using IF blocks would be very complicated.

## Question

Will SQL Server still check `a.UserId = a.UserId` on every row even though that condition will always be `true`, or will that condition be optimized out when it sees that `@UserId` is `NULL`?

If it would check `a.UserId = a.UserId` on every row, would it be more efficient to build a string like in *option 1*, or would it still be faster to do the `a.UserId = a.UserId` condition? Is that something that would depend on how many rows are in the tables?

Is there another option here that I should be considering? I wouldn't call myself a database expert by any means.

Comment: Option 2 is better. How about an inner join between the two tables with the ON b.UserId = a.UserId and remove that part from the WHERE.

Comment: @Chuck Like I said, I'm not DB expert, but I thought that was equivalent to this multi table select. Is that not true? Would **option 2** still be better if the table grew to a few million rows? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, because the COALESCE(@UserId, a.UserId) will be called only once. Using Option#1 the SQL server will have to compile the query each time, using Option 2 the stored procedure will be compiled and optimized once.

Comment: @Chuck, would you like to write that as an answer?

Comment: @Chuck Wouldn't only two execution plans be created for Option #1? I guess the SQL String still has to be created each time though before it can select 1 of the 2 execution plans.

Comment: Have you examined the actual execution plans? You can specify [query options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) such as `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` or `RECOMPILE` to alter the usual optimization for parameter values. Experiment and check the execution plans to see if you can achieve the desired result without dynamic SQL.

Comment: A must read: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). He mentions [The Coalesce Trap](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#coalesce) there as well.

Comment: @Chuck So optimized once.  It still has to execute

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Thanks for that resource! Excellent read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the best performance (and the lowest query cost) if you replace the COALESCE with a compound predicate as follows:

```
    (@UserId IS NULL OR a.UserId = @UserId)
```

I would also suggest when writing T-SQL that you utilize the join syntax rather than the antiquated ANSI-89 coding style. The revised query will look something like this:

```
    SELECT a.EntryId, a.Name, a.UserId, b.UserName
    FROM tblEntry a
      INNER JOIN tblUser b ON a.UserId = b.UserId
    WHERE a.EntryId = @EntryId
        AND (@UserId IS NULL OR a.UserId = @UserId);
```

Comment: I had read that there could be a slight gain in speed using `IS NULL OR` rather than `COALESCE` but now knowing about the *coalesce trap* I can see how this would be much better and more clear. Is dynamic SQL definitely not a good idea here because the SQL string has to be built on every execution of the stored procedure, would require more execution plans, and `@UserId IS NULL OR a.UserId = @UserId)` is a NOOP anyways?

Comment: @crush, `@UserId IS NULL OR a.UserId = @UserId` is a NOOP when you use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. If you don't use this option, it may affect the execution plan. And overall execution plan can easily become far from optimal without this option. The http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html discusses it in details.

Comment: Any reason that its recommended to write the joins instead of the multi-table select syntax? I read that they compiled into equivalent plans.

Comment: The join syntax is a modern SQL standard whereas the multi-table select syntax is based on an old SQL standard. Although most SQL engines are backward compatible, the join syntax communicates more clearly the developer's intent because it separates the join criteria from other table-specific criteria used to restrict the recordset.